# JavaScript - Erro ao carregar novos popover

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, laravel, popover

Eu tenho uma pagina que contem mosaico de imagens com um botao e ao clicar eu abro um popover. Até então ok, pois esse mosaico é gerado pelo *blade.php*, do laravel 5.
Mas eu altero o mosaico a partir de filtros na própria página e o popover para de funcionar, sendo que é gerado a partir do mesmo "codigo" html.

Codigo do *blade.php* (**HTML**), ou seja, estatico:

```
  <div class="avancar-mosaico" >
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div class="row" style="margin: 0px;">
            <div id="outer">
                @foreach($Emp as $emp)
                <div class="itemwrapper col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" style="padding: 0px;">
                  <img src="{{asset('/images/mosaico')}}/{{$emp->numF1}}-{{$emp->eixo}}-0{{$emp->numP1}}.png" alt="Imagem do empreendimento" />
                    <figcaption>
                        <a href="{{route('empreendimentos.view', ['id' => $emp->idn_empreendimento])}}">{{$emp->obra}}</a>
                        @if($emp->distancia == null)
                        <span class="info-municipio">{{$emp->cidade}},  {{$emp->estado}}</span>
                        @else
                        <span class="info-municipio">{{$emp->distancia}}</span>
                        @endif
                    </figcaption>
                    <!--{{$barra =  ($emp->execucao_fisica != 100) ? 'progress-bar-warning progress-extra': 'progress-bar-complete progress-extra'}}
                    {{$caminho = route('empreendimentos.view', ['id' => $emp->idn_empreendimento])."?ref=busca"}}-->                 
                  <div class="mosaico-botoes">
                    <a                            
                        data-template='
                        <div class="popover" role="tooltip">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-top seta-pop seta-pop-emp" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                            <div class="dbw-map-location-container"  style="color:gray">
                                <div class="dbw-map-location-info">
                                    <div class="dbw-map-location-info-details">
                                        <div class="empreendimento_estagio_titulo">ESTÁGIO DA OBRA</div>
                                        <center>
                                        <div class="progress progress-extra-2" sytle ="width: 90px;">
                                            <div class="progress-bar {{$barra}}" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="{{round($emp->execucao_fisica)}}" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:{{$emp->execucao_fisica}}%">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="row" style="text-align: left;margin-bottom: 20px;">
                                            <div class="col-md-6" style="border: 0;">
                                                <STRONG style="font-size: 24px" class = "empreendimento_perc_exec">{{round($emp->execucao_fisica)}}%&nbsp;•&nbsp;</STRONG>
                                            </div>
                                            <div style="font-size:14px;border: 0;padding-top: 14px;" class ="empreendimento_perc_status col-md-6">
                                                {{$emp->estagio}}
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="row" style="text-align: left;margin-bottom: 20px;">
                                            <div style="border: 0;" class="empreendimento_inicio_title col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                                                INICIO<br>
                                                <u class="empreendimento_dates" style="font-size: 20.5px;">
                                                {{format_date($emp->data_selecao)}}</u>
                                            </div>
                                            <div style="border: 0;" class="empreendimento_inicio_title col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                                                CONCLUSÃO<br>
                                                <u class="empreendimento_dates" style="font-size: 20.5px;">
                                                {{format_date($emp->data_conclusao)}}</u>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <center>
                                            <a href={{$caminho}} class="btn btn-primary btn-xs btn-avancar">Saiba mais</a>
                                        </center>
                                    </center>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>'    
                        data-content=' ' id="a3" style="cursor: pointer;width: 150px;" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom">
                        <img src={{asset('images/icone-grafico.svg')}}>
                    </a>
                    <a 
                        data-template='
                        <div class="popover popover-share" role="tooltip">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-top seta-pop seta-pop-share" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                            <div class="popover-arrow"></div>
                            <h3 class="popover-title"></h3>
                            <a class="avancar-sobre-compartihar" href="" target="_blank">
                                <img class="mosaico-share-icon" src={{asset("images/facebook.svg")}} ></img>
                                <u class="mosaico-share">&nbsp;Facebook</u>
                            </a>
                            <a class="avancar-sobre-compartihar" href={{$caminho}} target="_blank">
                                <img class="mosaico-share-icon" src={{asset("images/permalink.svg")}} ></img>
                                <u class="mosaico-share">&nbsp;Permalink</u>
                            </a>
                        </div>'
                        data-content=' ' class="icone-compartilhar" id="a3" style="cursor: pointer;" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom">

                        <img src={{asset('images/icone-compartilhar.svg')}}>
                    </a>
                  </div>
                </div>
                @endforeach
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Seguem imagem do mosaico com popover pelo blade do laravel:

[image: Mosaico com popover, estatico sem erro]

Aqui segue o **ajax**, somente parte da função *javascript* que é executada ao alterar o valor na combobox,ou seja, dinamico:

```
  $.ajax({
      type: 'get',
      url : 'populaMosaico',
      data: {'eixo': eixo, 'uf': local,'lat':lat,'lng':lng},
      dataType:'json',
      success: function(data){    
        try{
          var i = 0;         
          mosaico += '<div class="row" style="margin: 0px;">'+
                   '<div id="outer">';  */     
          for(i in data){

        if(data[i].execucao_fisica != 100){
          var choice = 'progress-bar-warning progress-extra';
        }else{
          var choice = 'progress-bar-complete progress-extra';
        }

        if(data[i].obra.length > 50){                          
          if(data[i].obra[50] == ' '){
            obra = data[i].obra.slice(0, 50) + ' ...';
          }else{
            var resto = data[i].obra.slice(50, data[i].obra.length);
            if(resto.substring(0, resto.indexOf(' ')) != '')
              resto = resto.substring(0, resto.indexOf(' '));
            obra = data[i].obra.slice(0, 50) + resto + ' ...';
        }
       }else{
        obra = data[i].obra;
      }

      mosaico += '<div class="itemwrapper col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" style="padding: 0px;">\n'+
                  '<img src="../images/mosaico/'+data[i].numF1+'-'+data[i].eixo+'-0'+data[i].numP1+'.png" alt="Imagem do empreendimento"/>\n'+
                  '<figcaption><a href="empreendimentos/'+data[i].idn_empreendimento+'/visualizar">'+obra+'</a>';

      if(data[i].distancia == null){
        var opt = data[i].cidade+','+data[i].estado;
        mosaico += '<span class="info-municipio">'+opt+'</span></figcaption>\n';
      }else{
        var opt = data[i].distancia;
        mosaico += '<span class="info-municipio"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-screnshot"></span>'+opt+' KM</span></figcaption>\n';
      }

      mosaico +=  '<div class="mosaico-botoes">'+
                  '<a\n'+                            
                      'data-template=\'\n'+
                      '<div class="popover" role="tooltip">\n'+
                          '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-top seta-pop seta-pop-emp" aria-hidden="true"></span>\n'+
                          '<div class="dbw-map-location-container"  style="color:gray">\n'+
                              '<div class="dbw-map-location-info">\n'+
                                  '<div class="dbw-map-location-info-details">\n'+
                                      '<div class="empreendimento_estagio_titulo">ESTÁGIO DA OBRA</div>\n'+
                                        '<center>\n'+
                                          '<div class="progress progress-extra-2" sytle ="width: 90px;">\n'+
                                              '<div class="progress-bar '+choice+'" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="'+data[i].execucao_fisica+'" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:'+data[i].execucao_fisica+'%">\n'+
                                              '</div>\n'+
                                          '</div>\n'+
                                          '<div class="row" style="text-align: left;margin-bottom: 20px;">\n'+
                                              '<div class="col-md-6" style="border: 0;">\n'+
                                                  '<STRONG style="font-size: 24px" class = "empreendimento_perc_exec">'+data[i].execucao_fisica+'%&nbsp;•&nbsp;</STRONG>\n'+
                                              '</div>\n'+
                                              '<div style="font-size:14px;border: 0;padding-top: 14px;" class ="empreendimento_perc_status col-md-6">\n'+
                                                  data[i].estagio+
                                              '</div>\n'+
                                          '</div>\n'+
                                          '<div class="row" style="text-align: left;margin-bottom: 20px;">\n'+
                                              '<div style="border: 0;" class="empreendimento_inicio_title col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">\n'+
                                                  'INICIO<br>\n'+
                                                  '<u class="empreendimento_dates" style="font-size: 20.5px;">'+data[i].data_selecao+'</u>\n'+
                                              '</div>\n'+
                                              '<div style="border: 0;" class="empreendimento_inicio_title col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">\n'+
                                                  'CONCLUSÃO<br>\n'+
                                                  '<u class="empreendimento_dates" style="font-size: 20.5px;">\n'+
                                                  ''+data[i].data_conclusao+'</u>\n'+
                                              '</div>\n'+
                                          '</div>\n'+
                                          '<center>\n'+
                                              '<a href="empreendimentos/'+data[i].idn_empreendimento+'/visualizar?ref=busca" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs btn-avancar">Saiba mais</a>\n'+
                                          '</center>\n'+
                                      '</center>\n'+
                              '</div>\n'+          
                            '</div>\n'+
                        '</div>\n'+
                    '</div>\'\n'+
                    'data-content=\' \' id="a3" style="cursor: pointer;width: 150px;" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-original-title data-title>'+
                      '<img src="../images/icone-grafico.svg">\n'+
                  '</a>\n'+
                  '<a \ndata-template=\'\n'+
                      '<div class="popover popover-share" role="tooltip">\n'+
                          '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-top seta-pop seta-pop-share" aria-hidden="true"></span>\n'+
                          '<div class="popover-arrow"></div>\n'+
                          '<h3 class="popover-title"></h3>\n'+
                          '<a class="avancar-sobre-compartihar" href="" target="_blank">\n'+
                              '<img class="mosaico-share-icon" src="../images/facebook.svg"></img>\n'+
                              '<u class="mosaico-share">&nbsp;Facebook</u>\n'+
                          '</a>\n'+
                          '<a class="avancar-sobre-compartihar" href="#" target="_blank">\n'+
                              '<img class="mosaico-share-icon" src="../images/permalink.svg"></img>\n'+
                              '<u class="mosaico-share">&nbsp;Permalink</u>\n'+
                          '</a>\n'+
                      '</div>\n'+
                      'data-content=\' \' class="icone-compartilhar" id="a3" style="cursor: pointer;" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom">\n'+
                      '<img src="../images/icone-compartilhar.svg">\n'+
                  '</a>\n'+
                '</div>\n'+
              '</div>\n';
    }
    /*mosaico += '</div>\n'+
              '</div>\n';*/
    $(document).find('#outer').html('');                       
    $(document).find('#outer').append(mosaico);

  }catch(err){
    alert("Nenhuma obra encontrado para o filtro");
    document.getElementsByClassName("avancar-header").style.display = 'none';
    removido = true;
    return;
  }                                    
 },
 error: function(){

 }
});
```

O mosaico gerado fica assim:
[image: Mosaico sem popover, dinamico e com erro]

O mosaico gerado fica esteticamente igual, mas o popover não funciona ao clicar em um dos dois botoes ao lado da localização. Alguem poderia me ajudar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver criando um onclick por cada botão.
O erro acontece pois o script do popover observa elementos que foram criados no momento da criação da pagina, depois disso é necessario chamar novamente algo para acompanahar novos elementos criados.